# Convert a Map<Object, Object> to a Json String

Tags: java, json

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    ...
}
```

Then I create a map like this:

```
Map<Person, String> map = new HashMap<Person, String>();
map.put(new Person("Bob", "Builder"), "string1");
map.put(new Person("Bob", "NotBuilding"), "string2");
```

What should a valid json representation of the above look like? if it is indeed possible?

Comment: don't use Person (an object) as the hash key, give the Person some id, and use that as a key. Store the Person itself somewhere else (also keyed with the same id).

Comment: I'm creating a custom json framework so I don't really have a way to enforce what people may or may not do. I was just curious as to how the above map would be represented not so much the validity of how the map is used even though I do understand your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a serialization/deserialization mechanism for class Person first. For example each Person may have a unique id, which can be used as the map key. Java uses its `hashCode()` for serializing Person object to a key.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "Persons" : { "string1" : { "class" : "Person", "firstName" : "Bob", "lastName" : "Builder" }, "string2" : { "class" : "Person", "firstName" : "Bob", "lastName" : "NotBuilding" } } }
```

This is only from a JSON stand point and assuming you name your map "Persons". You need to find a way to serialize and de-serialize but I guess you can find one in java.

Comment: Why would you map the value to the key as opposed to the key to the value? I guess my point is that the reason I asked my question was that converting an object such as 'Person' to a Json string would make for an invalid "name" in a 'name : value' pair due to the quotes embedded in the Person object.

Comment: Oh I got it the other way, although, I don't think it would be considered valid JSON to use the Person dictionary as a key.

Comment: It wouldn't be considered valid JSON to use the Person dictionary as a key unless you use some sort of a key for the Person object and one for the value like in: { "key" : { "class" : "Person" ...}, "value" : "string1" }, ...